# Serializing MethodBase and Exception types in a WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, service, datacontractserializer

I created a WCF service for logging exceptions (I realize if the network is down, things won't be logged...there are fallbacks in place)

Anyhow, it has two methods

```
int LogException(MethodBase methodBase, Exception exception)
int LogMessage(MethodBase methodBase, string message, string data)
```

When I try and add the service to a new project, the .cs file is not created.  I ran svcutil, and copied the .cs and config settings into the project, and tried calling the service with the generated client.  I got the following two error

> There was an error while trying to
>   serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:methodBase. The
>   InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo'
>   with data contract name
>   'RuntimeMethodInfo:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Reflection'
>   is not expected. Consider using a
>   DataContractResolver or add any types
>   not known statically to the list of
>   known types - for example, by using
>   the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.'. 
>   Please see InnerException for more
>   details.

With inner exception

> Type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo'
>   with data contract name
>   'RuntimeMethodInfo:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Reflection'
>   is not expected. Consider using a
>   DataContractResolver or add any types
>   not known statically to the list of
>   known types - for example, by using
>   the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When communicating via WCF, WCF needs to know precisely what will be sent across the boundary. So taking an "Exception" is fine and all, but almost always, you'll be passing subtypes of exception, so you need to tell the contract which types of Exceptions will be passed across the boundary. The same thing goes for MethodBase. You probably want to tell it that you'll actually be passing a MethodInfo some of the time.

Because these aren't your types, you probably can't use the KnownType attribute (the attribute usually gets placed on the base class or interface). In this case, you need to use a Data Contract Resolver. It tells the serialization / deserialization engine how to find the sub types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358759.aspx

Although you can use the ServiceKnownType attribute. Your contract should look something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public interface ILoggingStuff // choose a better name than this
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(MethodInfo))]
    int LogException(MethodBase methodBase, Exception exception);
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(MethodInfo))]
    int LogMessage(MethodBase methodBase, string message, string data);
}
```

This tells WCF that MethodBase could be using the descending Type MethodInfo.

Comment: @McKay, And where do I put this?

Comment: Sorry, slight memory lapse, you can't use KnownType, because they aren't your types (I was thinking about fault contracts, which are placed on the data contract)

Comment: I also found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes.aspx that mentions it would work for exceptions, but I don't know where to put the dataContractSerializer/dataTypes config info... in the svc or in the consuming app?

Comment: Oh, thanks for that link, my original comment would work as well, with the ServiceKnownType attribute. Updating original post.

Comment: @McKay, I still haven't managed to get it to work, and it appears the `MethodBase` type is causing serious issues too

Comment: @Chad look at the new code I just posted to the original answer. That should probably work?

Comment: @McKay, nope, it appears the problem is it becomes `RuntimeMethodInfo` which is an internal type that i can't instantiate, and thus can't seem to use `typeof(RuntimeMethodInfo)`

Comment: WCF needs to know detailed information at compile time about the type being passed across. If you can't tell it how to do that, then that means you can't pass it across a WCF communication layer. My suggestion would be to pass the important information across the WCF layer instead. Maybe you just want the stack trace? Just the calling method?

Comment: @McKay, there is a lot of information.  The idea was to simplify logging by passing in an object .Net already creates, not rely on developers to set all this information... which they WILL fail to do properly...

Comment: You could create a new type MethodData which only has one constructor which takes a MethodInfo as a parameter, so they'd have to call it thusly:  LogException(new MethodData(methodInfo), ex)

Comment: @McKay, that's what I've done.  Now I have the same issue with exceptions.  "Type 'System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal' with data contract name 'ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected.  Consider using a DataContractResolver..."

Comment: @Chad: you are learning, little by little, why not to pass data you have no control over, especially platform-specific types. Your code will break as soon as .NET starts using a different subtype of one of the types you are passing. This cannot work, in general. You need to decide what parts of MethodBase, and what parts of Exception you are interested in, and pass those instead.

Comment: Yeah, it's what I ended up doing.  Seems like a hack though since I already have an object with everything I want...  Ah well.